# ServiceStack - ApiMember Verb - Not Working

Tags: c#, servicestack

I have a DTO which I share for POST and GET method, and I want to have one extra field for GET method, so I tried using it like this:

```
//...
 [ApiMember(Name = "Status", Verb = "GET", Description = "Status", DataType = "string")]
        public string Status { get; set; }   
//...
```

But for some reason, it's still showing in Swagger-UI for both methods in documentation.

Verb says: `Gets or sets verb to which applies attribute. By default applies to all verbs.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The metadata attributes do not change the behavior or schema of a Service they're only used to document it.

If you want Services to have a different Schema for GET and POST requests they need to be in different Request DTOs, each with just the fields that are available for each verb, e.g:

```
[Route("/customers", "GET")]
class GetCustomer { ... }

[Route("/customers")]
class StoreCustomer { ... }

public class MyServices : Service
{
    public object Get(GetCustomer request) => ...;

    public object Any(StoreCustomer request) => ...;
}
```

Comment: So what then this `Verb` in `ApiMemberAttribute` represent? Oh, nvm, I just read your answer again... Ok, tnx.

Comment: @ShP If you have multiple routes, you can use it to document how it should appear for a particular route by also specifying the `Route` it applies to. E.g. you can move it to a path variable with: `[ApiMember(Route="/customers/{Status}", Verb = "GET", ParameterType="path"]`

Comment: I see, thanks. I thought it can be used like I mentioned earlier in common DTO and then just to play around little bit with Verb GET - POST - DELETE - PUT, it would be cool to have that option doe...